# How to add product specification information in admin product view page?

Tags: product, product-images, backend, upload, view

I am trying to add product specification section in admin product view page.
This section has to include three images upload function that display its specification, and then title input field, description textarea.
So that  I am trying to show to customer product's properties that has three images , image title and image description in the frontend product view page.
Please tell me example code.